# Puppeteer get URL from localhost

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

I have a website where I need to log in. After a short time of loading, Chrome shows the "connection refused" page. At that point, I need to get the URL.

I tried multiple approaches I found online, however, none of them worked in that case.

What I tried

```
const url = await page.url(); 
console.log(url)    //--> chrome-error://chromewebdata/



const url = await page.evaluate(() => document.location.href);
console.log(url);   //--> chrome-error://chromewebdata/
```

I also think it has nothing to do with the timing. Because if I try to use puppeteer to click the "Details" Butten everything works well, so I assume the page is loaded propperly at that point.

[image: connection refused]

Comment: Hard to help, your page is on localhost and the code is 100% fine. Please share a [mcve].

Comment: Also having the same issue... no solution yet

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `waitForNavigationMethod`? Maybe bury the `console.log` inside an `if` statement involving that method.

Comment: I tried that, unfortunately, it doesn't help, somehow the navigation to the localhost doesn't trigger the wait for navigation() it just times out after 30000ms. I also tried to add a timeout but even with that the console log remains chrome-error://chromewebdata/

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Chrome Devtools Protocol session to capture the requests and responses.

```
const client = await page.target().createCDPSession();
await client.send('Network.enable');

client.on('Network.requestWillBeSent', (e) => {
    if (e.request.url.includes("http://localhost/dead-url")) {
        console.log(e.request.url);
    }
});
```

While doing that you could also check for `e.redirectResponse`, but it's going to be there only for a successful redirect.

Answer (score 0):

It's the network issue. I used proxy and the ip was not in whitelist. after that it worked well.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35363668)